# Microsoft Chart Controls Assembly reference: howto move it to web.config

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, web-config

Currently, when I want to use Microsoft Chart Controls on a website, I need to add the following onto every aspx page where I want to use it:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Is there any way to move this to the web.config file, so that I don't have to put it on every page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the web.config? Whenever i've dragged a chart control onto a page, it's added the correct assemblies in web.config automatically. The only time it doesn't do this is when it's in an MVC project.

If you are using MVC, check out [this post](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Build-a-Dashboard-With-Microsoft-Chart-Controls.aspx) on how to integrate the charts with an MVC project

Answer (score 1):

You can add like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For detailed information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd453008.aspx